# Android Studio, Java. JobIntentService stops after i try to use method for getting device location

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Okay, so I'm trying to make a service that records sound amplitude, time, date and device location every 5 seconds. It records sound, time and date perfectly but the service seems to crash after I use updateGPS() method that you will see in the code (service stops, but app doesn't crash). As somebody who doesnt have much experience in coding, I would appreciate any help on how to fix this.

This is the code for service:

```
public class MyService extends JobIntentService {

    static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, MyService.class, 123, work);
    }
    FusedLocationProviderClient loc;
    MainActivity ma;
    public double lat;
    public double lon;
    public int x = 5;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private MediaRecorder rec;


    private String recFile() {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File soundDir = cw.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
        File file = new File(soundDir, "recFile" + ".mp3");
        return file.getPath();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        try {
            rec = new MediaRecorder();
            rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            rec.setOutputFile(recFile());
            rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            rec.prepare();
            rec.start();
            rec.getMaxAmplitude();
            while (MainActivity.b == true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    if (isStopped()) return;
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                }
                updateGPS();
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                int test = rec.getMaxAmplitude();
                Log.i("tag", "jacina: " + test);
                Log.i("t", "datum: " + date);
                Log.i("t1", "vreme: " + time);
                Log.i("t2", "latitude: " + lat);
                Log.i("t3", "longitude: " + lon);

            }
            rec.stop();
            rec.release();
            rec = null;
            deleteFile(recFile());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopCurrentWork() {
        return super.onStopCurrentWork();
    }

    private void updateValues(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    }

    private void updateGPS() {
        loc = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MyService.this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }else{
            if(ma != null){
                ma.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "location not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        loc.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                updateValues(location);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

This is only part of code that I think needs to be changed:

```
loc.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                updateValues(location);
            }
        });
```

And this is logcat message:

```
2022-01-25 16:43:14.304 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.projekat.MyService cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Executor
2022-01-25 16:43:14.306 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at com.example.projekat.MyService.updateGPS(MyService.java:128)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.306 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at com.example.projekat.MyService.onHandleWork(MyService.java:78)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.306 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:391)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.307 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:382)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.307 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.308 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.308 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.308 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-01-25 16:43:14.309 29189-29595/com.example.projekat W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" to your service present in manifest.xml?

Comment: I did add that, that service worked fine before i added location tracking code

Comment: You are not paying attention to the exception. You are trying to cast your service class into executor, which it is not and hence the exception. Look at the exception: loc.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this,...
Correct this statement and the crash will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission `android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE` in the Manifest and add `android:exported="..."`

```
 <service android:name="com.narendra.example.MyService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>
```